# SQL Select each row multiple times depending on the row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have a table of this form:

```
ID   value
1    2
2    1
3    4
```

What's the **most efficient** way to select each row `value` times?

The desired output of the query is

```
ID
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will most probably be product specific.)

Comment: I am using TSQL, but was looking for a generic solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a numbers table, you can do:

```
select t.id
from t join
     numbers n
     on n.n <= t.value;
```

There are various ways to construct a numbers table.  Here is a brute force way that works in most databases:

```
select t.id
from t join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
     on n.n <= t.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Numbers table..

```
select id from #test t
cross apply
(select N  from dbo.numbers where n<t.num) b
```

**Output:**

```
id
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @MAX int;
SET @MAX = (SELECT MAX(VALUE) from vTable);

WITH R AS (SELECT 1 N 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT N + 1 FROM R WHERE N < @MAX),

      AllROWS AS (SELECT 
                    V.ID , 
                    V.Value, 
                    row_number() OVER (Partition BY v.id ORDER BY v.id) CNT
                   FROM vTable v
                    CROSS JOIN 
                R)
    SELECT ID FROM ALLROWS  WHERE CNT <= value                
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

I overcomplicated the above, you only need

```
DECLARE @MAX int;
SET @MAX = (SELECT MAX(VALUE) from vTable);

WITH R AS (SELECT 1 N 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT N + 1 FROM R WHERE N < @MAX)
    SELECT vTable.ID FROM R CROSS JOIN vTable WHERE R.N <= vTable.value ORDER BY vTable.Id            
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: And what is `vTable`?

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov - that's what I called his table with ID and value in it - I guess I should have called it YourTable